# Cash on delivery method not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

[image]

We enabled **cash on delivery** for UAE only and **2checkout** for all countries. When I select UAE as billing adress and shipping adresss as different place in UAE then both payment methods are showing. But problem when I select different country as billing address and UAE as shipping adsress at that time only 2checkout is showing. I am using lotusbreath one page checkout.

Answer (score 2):

For my knowledge Magento will work like that only.

The Drop down options you see in backend will work for Country selected in **Billing address** only  not for **shipping address**